# "ReferenceError: window is not defined" while installing "branchio-sdk" in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm new to nodejs development, well I installed "branch-sdk" module in nodejs, After including module it's giving error !

Referred Link - 
https://docs.branch.io/pages/web/integrate/

[please refer here for the error snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rvq8.png)

Comment: Can you provide some could you tried to use?

Comment: branchio-sdk has to be used in a browser context, it cannot be used with nodejs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you elaborate more as in why we can't use with nodejs @yadejo 
Well I've resolved that error by globally declaring window object and then I got error for window.navigator which again I resolved it by declaring it globally.

global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js'
};

global.window = {
  userAgent: 'node.js'
};

But now I'm stuck at "window.setTimeout is not a function"

Comment: Use this package to mock the window object in a non-browser environment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found Another method to initalize and use branchio using javascript

```js
(function(b,r,a,n,c,h,_,s,d,k){if(!b[n]||!b[n]._q){for(;s<_.length;)c(h,_[s++]);d=r.createElement(a);d.async=1;d.src="https://cdn.branch.io/branch-latest.min.js";k=r.getElementsByTagName(a)[0];k.parentNode.insertBefore(d,k);b[n]=h}})(window,document,"script","branch",function(b,r){b[r]=function(){b._q.push([r,arguments])}},{_q:[],_v:1},"addListener applyCode autoAppIndex banner closeBanner closeJourney creditHistory credits data deepview deepviewCta first getCode init link logout redeem referrals removeListener sendSMS setBranchViewData setIdentity track validateCode trackCommerceEvent".split(" "), 0);
    branch.init('some_key_defined', function(err, data) {
      
       var result = $.parseJSON(data.data);
       var Url= result.$canonical_url;
      window.location=Url;
});
```